# How to trigger a generic event through code

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

**Page Events** (defined in /sitecore/system/settings/Analytics/Page Events) cann be triggered like this:

```
var pageEventDefinition = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.PageEvents[pageEventId];
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.RegisterPageEvent(pageEventDefinition);
```

How can I trigger a **Generic Event**? (defined in /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Events)

[image]

There is no property for these on the `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.MarketingDefinitions` object.

Comment: Generic Events are being used by System as System event so I don't think we should touch it, do you have any specific requirement for this?

Comment: What happens when you try to get a system event by id from Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.PageEvents?

Comment: @grg Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.PageEvents doesn't contain these genereic events. I've tried that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with `Definition managers` as well, these are used to get marketing activities including the events. below example is to get the get definition manager in a Sitecore context and after that, you can get the event with the event id -

```
 IDefinitionManager<IEventDefinition> eventDefinitionManager = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetDefinitionManagerFactory().GetDefinitionManager<IEventDefinition>();
 Guid eventId = Guid.Parse("YourEventID");
 //below line will give you the latest active version
 IEventDefinition marketingEvent = eventDefinitionManager.Get(eventId, new CultureInfo("da"));
 //you need to convert the marketing event into IPageEventDefinition
 Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.RegisterPageEvent((IPageEventDefinition)marketingEvent);
```

If you will see the inheritance of the `Page Event` items it is inheriting the `Event` template which is the same template use to create Generic events and in the `RegisterPageEvent` code its ultimately converting the `IPageEventDefinition` into `IEventDefinition` and calling a protected `Register` method.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to agree with the comment above that system events should not be used by custom implementations, but if you really need that, you can create PageEventDefinition manually and register the event:

```
    Item pageViewItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID("{9326CB1E-CEC8-48F2-9A3E-91C7DBB2166C}"));
    PageEventDefinition pageViewEvent = new PageEventDefinition(pageViewItem.ID.Guid, pageViewItem.Name, Sitecore.Context.Culture, pageViewItem.Name, pageViewItem.Statistics.Created, pageViewItem.Statistics.CreatedBy);
    Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.RegisterPageEvent(pageViewEvent);
```